# Proof Of Authority vs Proof Of Work geth

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, proof-of-authority

In case of proof of work consensus mechanism miners compete with each other to solve the cryptographic puzzle and once a miner found the answer of puzzle , he will broadcast it to all the nodes participating in blockchain network. Majority of miners need to agree and validate the block using answer sent by miner and block is appended to blockchain.

In case of proof of authority, how sealers/signers validate blocks?

EDIT 1 :

[This question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13736/what-are-the-limitations-of-proof-of-authority) suggest that in case of Proof of Authority consensus mechanism signers sign blocks in round robin fashion ,Agreed ! My question is what procedure signers follow to sign a valid block? How do they identify invalid block? In case of proof of work node can validate block based on answer of cryptographic puzzle sent by miner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the limitations of proof of authority](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13736/what-are-the-limitations-of-proof-of-authority)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof of authority relies on a certain set of trusted nodes, known as "authorities" who are specifically granted the ability to secure the blockchain by verifying transactions and creating new blocks. Validation of the transactions in new blocks by other nodes is done exactly the same as proof of work.

Since this consensus algorithm depends on trusted nodes, it can only really be used for private or test chains.

Comment: EOS upcoming public mainnet is practically proof-of-authority network - what they have decentralized is how trusted nodes are selected.